# Problems using a MCP3008 and a MCP23S17 on SPI with WebIOPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, webiopi

I'm very new to WebIOPi and I'm trying my first tests. First of all I apologize for my english.
I'm trying to get to work a RPi with a `MCP3008` on CE0 and a `MCP23S17` on CE1 with SPI bus.

My problem is that devices only work when connected on CE1 (so, when 23017 is on CE0 I am not able to set pins to be inputs or outputs and to set it on 1 or 0, but 3008 is on CE1 and I see its levels changing. When - vice versa - 23017 is on CE1 it is fully functional, but 3008 outputs stay still).

Due to this, I think it is not an hardware issue (I don't have much expertise in electronics, but luckily I don't build my circuits by myself :) ), I think it is a problem in WebIOPi config. Here is my WebIOPi config:

```
[DEVICES]
mcp1 = MCP23S17 chip:1 slave:0x27
adc0 = MCP3008 chip:0
```

I only added these two lines to my config file.
I did not touch anything else of my original WebIOPi installation.

In this case (adc0 fully functional, mcp1 not working), when loading the WebIOPi devices monitor I see adc0 levels working good and mcp1 pins randomly changing between being a input and an output and from 0 and 1.
May it be a config error?

Answer (score 0):

Use python and spidev module instead! Look my answer on another thread for function for the mcp3008 chip.